# Different errors compiling C using Codeblocks

Tags: c, codeblocks, undefined-reference

I want to compile a file using Codeblocks.

This main file calls other C files. When I build and run it, I have several errors in my console.

First, I have this error: ===Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler unknown) ===. I think that error is because I'm not trying to run a project but a single file.

Second, I have many "undefined reference to 'name_of_a_function' " errors. And I do not know why because all the functions are defined in the other files.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a project to compile the file.

A similar question in [Code::Blocks user forums](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=20579.0):

> I don't have a project, just wonted to compile and debug a single
>   file. Is there a way to accomplish this without creating a project?

and the answer:

> Nope.

Btw, why don't you use simple `cc` command to compile the file just like this?

```
cc test.c -o test
```